# JPA аннотация @OrderBy не сортирует записи

Tags: java, jpa

у меня есть пара сущностей, Master и Padawan, один мастер может иметь несколько падаванов.

Мне требуется чтобы при чтении из базы мастера, в поле padawans была сортировка по поле age:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Master {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("age")
    private List<Padawan> padawans = new ArrayList<>();

    public Master(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Padawan {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public int age;

    public Padawan(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Padawan{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

и сам класс, из которого произвожу запуск:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myUnit");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        Master master = new Master("Kwigon Jeen");
        Padawan padawan1 = new Padawan("Obi One", 15);
        Padawan padawan2 = new Padawan("Lee", 19);
        Padawan padawan3 = new Padawan("Ganz", 13);
        Collections.addAll(master.getPadawans(), padawan1, padawan2, padawan3);

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(master);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        factory.getCache().evictAll();

        Master res;
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        res = entityManager.find(Master.class, master.getId());
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        res.getPadawans().stream().forEach(padawan -> System.out.println(padawan));

        entityManager.close();
        factory.close();
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что список padawans выводится неотсортированным.

> Padawan{id=1, name='Obi One', age=15} Padawan{id=2, name='Lee',
>   age=19} Padawan{id=3, name='Ganz', age=13}

p.s.

1) Пробовал совсем убрать Lombok

2) Пробовал изменить цикл вывода со стримов на foreach:

```
  for (Padawan p : res.getPadawans()){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
```

3) Менял цикл вывода на foreachOrdered

```
res.getPadawans().stream().forEachOrdered(padawan -> System.out.println(padawan));
```

Comment: Попробуйте обойти результат вызова `getPadawans()` в обычном цикле или использовать `forEachOrdered`.

Comment: Аннотации гетеров и сетеров это ломбок? Он может блокировать магию вашей jpa реализации.

Comment: @Maxim к сожалению не помогло(выпилил весь ломбок, заменил на геттеры-сеттеры+конструкторы руками)

Comment: @Hivemaster попробовал оба вариант, не повлияло.

Comment: Поменяйте `factory.getCache().evictAll()` на `entityManager.clear()`

Comment: @Serodv Да, оформите пожалуйста как ответ

Comment: почему бы не использовать orderBy в Restrictions? быстро и просто.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931203/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: это был мой вопрос..но там где то по середине есть кусок java кода..на 5~7строк.там есть сортировка по orderBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь получить осортированный список, который уже есть в кеше 1-го уровня, очистив при этом кеш 2-го уровня. Hibernate не обращает внимание на порядок сортировки списка в кеше, ему важно лишь его наличие чтобы не формировать запрос к базе (аннотация @OrderBy влияет на порядок только при получении данных). Соответственно для генерации запроса и получения отсортированного списка можно либо очистить кеш 1-го уровня:

```
entityManager.clear();
```

либо отсоединить объект от контекста:

```
entityManager.detach(master);
```

либо пересоздать контекст:

```
entityManager.close();
entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```